# OpenMP in Biham-Middleton-Levine BML model

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, automaton

I've got a serial version of BML and I'm trying to write a parallel one with OpenMP. Basically my code works with a `main` witin a loop calling two functions for horizontal and vertical moves. Like that:

```
for (s = 0; s < nmovss; s++) {
        horizontal_movs(grid, N);
        copy_sides(grid, N);
        cur = 1-cur;
        vertical_movs(grid, N);
        copy_sides(grid, N);
        cur = 1-cur;
}
```

Where `cur` is the current grid. Then horizontal and vertical functions are similar and have a nested loop:

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for(j = 1; j <= n+1; j++) {
        if(grid[cur][i][j-1] == LR && grid[cur][i][j] == EMPTY) {
            grid[1-cur][i][j-1] = EMPTY;
            grid[1-cur][i][j] = LR;
        }
        else {
            grid[1-cur][i][j] = grid[cur][i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

The code produces a ppm image at every step, and whit a certain input the serial version produce an output that we can suppose good. But using `#pragma omp parallel for` inside the two functions H and V, the ppm file results splitted in such zones as the number of threads(i.e. 4):

[image: final step]

I suppose the problem is that every thread should be doing both functions in sequence before termitate because movememnts are strictcly connected. I don't know how to do that. If I set pragma at a highter level like before main loop, there is no speed-up. Obviously the ppm file has to be not sliced like the image.

Comment: Just a super wild guess as the level of details you give is way to limited (just show the actual parallelized code, that would be much more useful), you forgot to declare `private( j )` in your `#pragma omp parallel for` line. Just try adding it and see what happens.

Comment: @Gilles `default(none), shared and private` are omitted in the question but there are in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Goin'on I tried this solution that gives me an identical result as the serial code, but I don't excatly understand why

```
#   pragma omp parallel num_threads(thread_count) default(none) \
    shared(grid, n, cur) private(i, j)
    for(i = 1; i <= n+1; i++) {
#       pragma omp for
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if(grid[cur][i-1][j] == TB && grid[cur][i][j] == EMPTY) {
                grid[1-cur][i-1][j] = EMPTY;
                grid[1-cur][i][j] = TB;
            }
            else {
                grid[1-cur][i][j] = grid[cur][i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore, if i use just one thread more than available cores(4), the execution time "explodes" instead of remain barely the same.